# How do i sum given range in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, range

[Pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVeFP.png)

Hi i have dataframe where i want to sum the range of columns(CE_net, PE_net, CE_chg, PE_chg) where the column strike are from 17000 to 17500 and i cant pass direct values like 17000:17500. I want to pass the range through variables like start:end

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Ok i did this  
#First got index of values 
index1= np.where(df["column_name"]==value1)[0][0] 
index2= np.where(df["column_n.ame"]==value2)[0][0]           
index2 = index2 +1 
#Then                                   

df.iloc[index1:index2, 3:4].sum()[0]
```

Comment: This assumes that you reference column ("column_name") is ordered. Is this always going to be the case?